# How to get a uniqueId for the following colum in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following column in my pandas dataframe named as `FailureLabel`

```
   ID  FailureLabel       
0   1              1      
1   2              1  
2   3              1  
3   4              0       
4   5              0       
5   6              0  
6   7              0        
7   8              1        
8   9              1        
9   10             0
10  11             0
11  12             1     
12  13             1
```

I would like to assign a `unique_id` to this column such that eachs 1's have a unique id whereas all zeros + the next one have a common "unique id".

I tried using the following code ,

```
df['unique_id'] = (df['FailureLabel'] | (df['FailureLabel']!=df['FailureLabel'].shift())).cumsum()
```

which gives me the following output,

```
   ID  FailureLabel       unique_id
0   1              1      1
1   2              1      2
2   3              1      3
3   4              0      4 
4   5              0      4
5   6              0      4
6   7              0      4 
7   8              1      5  
8   9              1      6  
9   10             0      7
10  11             0      7
11  12             1      8
12  13             1      9
```

But what I desire is,

```
   ID  FailureLabel       unique_id
0   1              1      1
1   2              1      2
2   3              1      3
3   4              0      4 
4   5              0      4
5   6              0      4
6   7              0      4 
7   8              1      4  
8   9              1      5  
9   10             0      6
10  11             0      6
11  12             1      6
12  13             1      7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with backfilling first value, compare by `1` and add cumulative sum:

```
df['unique_id'] = df['FailureLabel'].shift().bfill().eq(1).cumsum()

print (df)
    ID  FailureLabel  unique_id
0    1             1          1
1    2             1          2
2    3             1          3
3    4             0          4
4    5             0          4
5    6             0          4
6    7             0          4
7    8             1          4
8    9             1          5
9   10             0          6
10  11             0          6
11  12             1          6
12  13             1          7
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution. +1 from me

Comment: @jezrael, can you check this pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70183007/pandas-column-perform-max-min-operation-on-continous-rows

Comment: @jezrael Thank you for the solution. Would you mind to answer the exact opposite of this question? That is the desired unique_id for the above FailureLabel should be 1,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7

Comment: @jezrael Okay, I found it you don't need to do shift. i.e. df['FailureLabel'].bfill().eq(1).cumsum()