# Pandas column perform max/min operation on continous rows

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to  maximum amount on salary column and minimum amount on expense column
for continuous valid numbers (not null values )

I tried iterating rows but not working properly, looking for a pandas way solution.

```
Name   date    salary  expense
Ram    10      1000    NaN
Ram    12      8000    NaN
Ram    13      NaN     500
Ram    14      NaN     800
Ram    15      3000    NaN
```

My expected output will be like this,

```
Name   date    salary  expense
Ram    12      8000    NaN
Ram    13      NaN     500
Ram    15      3000    NaN
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: df.iterrows with for loop but looking for pandas solution

Comment: update your question with your iterrows attempt please

Comment: Are salary and expense always exclusive? If not, can you provide a example for this case?

Comment: salary and expense will not be present in a same row?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the 'salary' and 'expense' are exclusive in a row, craft a custom group, sort the values to get the max salary and min expense first, and get the first row per group after sorting:

```
group = df['salary'].isna().diff().fillna(False).cumsum()
(df.sort_values(by=['salary', 'expense'], ascending=[False, True])
   .groupby(group).first()
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

output:

```
  Name  date  salary  expense
0  Ram    12  8000.0      NaN
1  Ram    13     NaN    500.0
2  Ram    15  3000.0      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for processing rows per maximum and minimal value per column separately with join in last step:

```
df['g1'] = df['salary'].isna().cumsum()
df['g2'] = df['expense'].isna().cumsum()

df1=df.loc[df.groupby(['Name','g1'])['salary'].idxmax().dropna(),['Name','date','salary']]
df2=df.loc[df.groupby(['Name','g2'])['expense'].idxmin().dropna(),['Name','date','expense']]

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  Name  date  salary  expense
0  Ram    12  8000.0      NaN
1  Ram    13     NaN    500.0
2  Ram    15  3000.0      NaN
```